# How to create data model for multipled catagories in kotlin for android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

For Example, i have many layered categories like this;

MainCategory(SubCategory1, SubCategory2, SubCategory3, SubCategory4)

SubCategory(Category1, Category2, Category3, Category4)

Category(Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4)

Item -> Some Attributes

I want to save in db "item" associating with the user. How should I create a data structure?

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: I hadn't thought yet.

Answer (score 1):

Start by defining your "Item" Data model first:

```
data class Day(
    val name:String,
    val temperature:Double
)
```

Then proceed with defining One-layer above. The "Category" like this:

```
data class WeatherEntry(
    val id:Int?=null,
    val date: String,
    @Embedded
    val day: Day
)
```

Repeat the process till you are done with top-most layer. At the final layer, to store the "Main Item" in your DB, do this:

```
val day=Day("Monday", 25.5)
val weatherEntry=WeatherEntry(1,"19/4/22",day)

// push this entry to firebase here
```